# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

Could someone correct this code:

```
echo "<div style="float:right;"><a href='index.php?img1=$img1_id&img2=$img2_id'><img src='$img1_url' /></a></br>Asd: $img1_asd</div>";
echo "<div style="float:right;"><a href='index.php?img1=$img2_id&img2=$img1_id'><img src='$img2_url' /></a></br>Asd: $img1_asd</div>";
```

I'm getting the error which is specified in the title

Comment: Start by escaping your quotes within quotes - this is PHP 101 stuff

Comment: You have to escape the " in your string.

Comment: Start with [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Learn Escape Sequence](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/2) .

```
echo "<div style=\"float:right;\"><a href='index.php?img1=$img1_id&img2=$img2_id'><img src='$img1_url' /></a></br>Asd: $img1_asd</div>"; 
echo "<div style=\"float:right;\"><a href='index.php?img1=$img2_id&img2=$img1_id'><img src='$img2_url' /></a></br>Asd: $img1_asd</div>"
```

Comment: yup thanks, I was silly enough to forget to escape my quotes

Comment: It contains code-mess and invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div style="float:right;"><a href="index.php?img1='.$img1_id.'&img2='.$img2_id.'><img src='.$img1_url.' /></a></br>Asd: '.$img1_asd.'</div>';

echo '<div style="float:right;"><a href="index.php?img1='.$img2_id.'&img2='.$img1_id.'><img src='.$img2_url.' /></a></br>Asd: '.$img1_asd.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Come on you can do better...

```
echo "<div style='float:right;'>",
     "<a href='index.php?img1=", $img1_id, "&amp;img2=", $img2_id, "'>",
     "<img src='", $img1_url, "' />",
     "</a><br />",
     "Asd: ", $img1_asd",
     "</div>";
```

This even has `&` correctly escaped to `&amp;`

Remember, closing void tags is only neccessary for XHTML: `<br />`
not in HTML4 and HTML5.

This is even wrong³: `</br>`